# drag and drop not working properly as intended

Tags: jquery, html

its type of quiz here i want to drop any 1 option either (a),(b),(c),(d) in any of 1 textbox............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/962/

```
  <div class="ans_set1">
     <input type="text" maxlength="10" class="ans_set1_1" />
    <br><input type="text"  maxlength="0" class="ans_set1_2" />
    <br><input type="text" maxlength="0" class="ans_set1_3" />
   <br><input type="text" maxlength="0" class="ans_set1_4" />
 </div>



<div class="abcd">
<div class="a" id="draggable"><b>(a)</b>
</div>
<div class="b" id="draggable"><b>(b)</b>
</div>
<div class="c" id="draggable"><b>(c)</b>
</div>
<div class="d" id="draggable"><b>(d)</b>
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $(".a,.b,.c,.d").draggable({
        revert: true,
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    });
    $(".ans_set1_1,.ans_set1_2,.ans_set1_3,.ans_set1_4").droppable({
        accept: ".a,.b,.c,.d",
        drop: function (event, ui) {

         }
      });
   });
 } );



         jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/962/
```

Comment: jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/962/

Comment: Nothing can be put into a input text element except raw text.  Your "(a)"s and so on are `<div>` elements.  I would recommend changing your drop-in target to a `table` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/963/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(".a,.b,.c,.d").draggable({
            revert: true,
            helper: 'clone',
            start: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
            }
        });
        $(".ans_set1_1,.ans_set1_2,.ans_set1_3,.ans_set1_4").droppable({
            accept: ".a,.b,.c,.d",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                  var $answer=ui.draggable;
                  var $input=$(event.target);

                  var val=$answer.text()

                  $input.val(val);
            }
        });
    });
});
```